# AVplayer not playing video from iPhone gallery

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

So, this code was working fine in my previous project tested on iPhone 5s, but when I embedded it in my main project it's not working, it selects the video from gallery, shows player but keeps searching for the video-(won't play it), only the black Player screen with searching indicator below and pause button controls etc.

Also they only error I get in output window is :

> [1524:458877] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Searched it a lot and concluded from one of the answers at Apple forums that it doesn't effect anything and better goes ignored.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class GalleryVideoSelectorViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

let ipc = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ipc.delegate=self

}
@IBAction func SelectVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    ipc.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    ipc.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
    present(ipc,animated:true,completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func PlayBackVideo(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "LullabyURL") {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController,animated:true)
        {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }
}
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker:UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String:Any])
{
    ipc.dismiss(animated:true){

        var videourl = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL
        if let videoURL = videourl{

            defaults.set(videoURL,forKey: "LullabyURL")
            let player = AVPlayer(url:videourl!)
            print (videourl!)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.present(playerViewController,animated:true)
            {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the updated version of my delegate which was actually causing the problem.

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker:UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey:Any])
{
    ipc.dismiss(animated:true){
       let videourl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL
            UserDefaults.standard.set(videourl,forKey: "LullabyURL")
            let player = AVPlayer(url: videourl)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.present(playerViewController,animated:true)
            {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
    }
}
```

Changed "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey:Any]" to "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey:Any]"

and 
video Url from "let videourl = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL" to "let videourl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as! URL"